# Lotus script if condition not do exit sub

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I try to show messagebox only 1 time if user input "number < somevalue(days)" for warning to user input a new value that's bigger than somevalue. I try to check my code but I didn't find a problem why it's do repeat to show messagebox more than 1 times. [this code I code on Existing event]

```vb
Sub Exiting(Source As Field)
    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
    Set doc = uidoc.Document

    Dim diff As Long

    Set ComDate = doc.getFirstItem("CompletionDate").dateTimeValue
    Set DueDate = doc.GetFirstItem("DueDate").dateTimeValue

    diff = ComDate.TimeDifference(DueDate)  
    Dim days As Integer
    days=diff/86400
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim num As String
    num=uidoc.FieldGetText("DeliveryTiming")
    number= Cint(num)
    If(number<days) Then 
        Messagebox( "Please specify your request DeliveryTiming?" ),16,"Required input"
        Call uidoc.GotoField( "DeliveryTiming" )
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here. Are you saying (1) that the uesr is exiting the field and the code executes and gives the warning, but then the code executes and gives the warning again even though the user didn't exit the field again?  Or are you saying (2) that the user is exiting the field, it executes and gives the warning, then the user exits the field again and so it executes and gives the warning again but you want to stop it from doing the second warning??

Comment: I think my problem likes is saying(2) when user exiting that's field and I want to warning only 1 times , when have warning to show warning "information" have "OK" button but when user click on "OK"  it's still continued to show messagebox again and more than 1 time. then I want to stop its.

Comment: Sounds like you need a field on the form called something like "WarningDisplayed" which you clear during PostOpen or ModeChange (or all the above depending on your requirements) and then part of your test whether to display the message box is to check the field.  If it's cleared, display the box and set the field.  If not, move on.

Comment: Yes, a hidden field was going to be my suggestion, although I think a global variable that is declared and initialized for the form's scripting would also work. If you go with the field approach, a hidden computed for display field would give you the warning once (at most) per time editing the doc, whereas a hidden computed field would give you one warning per doc for the entire lifetime of the doc.

Comment: Thank you for your all suggestion .